# After opening csv file into wordpad ,i don't want double quotes for the field name in head section

Tags: php, mysql

When I export data to csv file and open file with wordpad myfield Sr. No. looks like "Sr. No."  in head section .I don't want it in double quotes in head section (column names).Code is as follow.

```
    $filename = "file.csv";
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');           
    $array = array('Sr. No.','Name','DOB','Address');
    $header = str_replace('',' ', $array);
    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    fputcsv($fp, $header);
    $query = "select * from registratin";
    $result = mssql_query($query);
    $i = 1;
    while($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)) {
      $row = array_merge(array($i), $row);
      fputcsv($fp, $row);
      $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation for fputcsv function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

"enclosure" parameter.